# Load heatmap with custom table data

Tags: highcharts

I would like to create Heatmap with n number of columns using Hightcharts library.

Data source is some backend api.

column1, column2, column n will have heatmap values.

In the y axis, I can have maximum of 6 columns. (2 columns in first image, 3 columns in second image)

The above are will not have heatmap data.

My requirement image:
[image: My requirement image attached]

I want to know how to provide data to heat map for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically download this data from a google sheet, you can use the [data](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js) module and use `googleAPIKey`, `googleSpreadsheetKey`, `googleSpreadsheetRange` and the `parsed()` function to properly parse this data.

```js
data: {
    googleAPIKey: 'YOUAPIKEY',
    googleSpreadsheetKey: 'YOUSPREADSHEETKEY',
    googleSpreadsheetRange: 'Sheet1!C1:ZZZ4',
    parsed: function (columns) {
        const chart = this.chart,
                    columnsCopy = [...columns],
                    parsedXCategories = [],
                    parsedYCategories = [],
                    parsedData = [];

        /* 
        Properly parse data and categories from columnsCopy
        (such parsing will differ depending on the structure of the data in spreadsheet, vertical or horizontal)
        */

        chart.update({
            xAxis: {
                categories: parsedXCategories
            },
            yAxis: {
                categories: parsedYCategories
            },
            series: [{
                keys: ['x', 'y', 'value'],
                data: parsedData
            }]
        });

        return false;
    }
},
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r9et04xq/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.googleAPIKey